# Nginx root location

Tags: nginx, configuration, location, vhosts

On our server we have the `/var/www/root/html/web/`  directory that contains all the code, and a `/var/www/root/html/web/front/` that contains our static frontend code.

Our frontend communicates with the code only via REST API calls, which have the `/api/` prefix, so all the calls will be accessible via `ourdomain.com/api/products/` , `ourdomain.com/api/products/45` and so on. We also have an admin running there, on `ourdomain.com/admin`

When we want to see the actual frontend, we have to go to `ourdomain.com/front` in the browser, which is of course not what we want.

We have, among other stuff, this in our config:

```
root /var/www/html/web;
index index.php index.html;

location /front {
        # some magic to make sure the /front folder will not be parsed
        index nothing_will_match;
        autoindex on;
    }
```

However, what we wish is that if you go to `ourdomain.com` it will load `/var/www/html/web/front/` folder as root, and if you go to `ourdomain.com/api/*` or `ourdomain.com/admin/*` it will load the `/var/www/html/web/` as root. Is that possible?

NOTE: the `/var/www/html/web/front/` folder can be moved somewhere else if needed, to `/var/www/html/front/` for example

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive (instead of `root`) to rewrite the URI:

```
root /var/www/html/web/front;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
}

location /api {
    alias /var/www/html/web/;
}
location /admin {
    alias /var/www/html/web/;
}
```